Existence of parallel transport
On Petersen’s Riemannian geometry textbook page 236 he prove the existence of parallel transport along a curve by first choosing a frame along the curve, however I cannot see why such frame exists on all of the curve without using the result of parallel transport?
The only way I think of is to partition the interval to small segments so that each one lies in a coordinate chart, and I can choose a frame along the segments one by one. But such frame might not smooth.
So did I miss something in the book or the arthor thinks this can be avoided using other methods？

To prove the existence of parallel transport along a curve, it suffices to find a frame in the neighborhood of each point on the curve. To do this choose local coordinates and use the coordinate vector fields as the frame. This works even if the parameterized curve does not have everywhere nonzero velocity or is not injective.

@Deane, you mean we can prove the parallel transport locally then glue them together using uniqueness? Ok, so I'm just wondering why Petersen use the global argument without any illustrations...

Yes, that’s what I meant. As others have indicated, it’s also not hard to glue together local oriented frames into a global one.

@Deane, for a beginner like me, glue together frames smoothly is quite sutle. XD

The simplest exercise to solve is to consider two maps $\gamma_1 : [0,2/3)\hookrightarrow SO(n)$ and $\gamma_2 : (1/3, 1] \hookrightarrow SO(n)$ and then try to make a smooth map $\gamma:[0,1]\hookrightarrow SO(n)$ such that $\gamma$ restricts to $\gamma_1$ on $[0, 2/3)$ and to $\gamma_2$ on $(3/4, 1]$.
If you can do this, then the rest is just chasing diagrams between charts for the general case.
Hint: Start with the cases $n=2$ and then $n=3$. For one approach of the general case you will need to understand more about the structure of $SO(n)$, in particular its lie algebra.

On the intersection of two coordinate charts with coordinate frames $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively, there is a $GL(n)$-valued function $M$ along the piece of the curve that lies in the intersection of the two charts such that  $F_2 = F_1M$. Now extend $M$ to the piece of the curve in the second chart.

A curve $\gamma : I \hookrightarrow M$ with a frame on it defines a curve $I \hookrightarrow O(n)$, but remember $O(n)$ is a group. You can multiply the chart components by a matrix to ensure $I\hookrightarrow SO(n)$ and then it's only a matter of manipulating these by connecting the disconnected ends to end up with a fully smooth embedding.
If you don't like this line of reasoning, you can also consider the lifted map $\tilde{\gamma}$ to the universal cover, in which case the entire path image fits in a single chart; you can make any choice of frame, including the constant frame $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$, and then simply push it forward.
Edit: in other words, your construction is correct; you can ameliorate discontinuities at the chart overlaps by modifying the frames slightly.

Thanks for the quick answer but I cannot understand how is the curve into orthogonal group defined if I dont use the result of this question. Also I think I need smoothness on overlaps not just continuity.


You pick a chain of charts $(U_i, \phi_i)$ that overlap only on $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$.
You choose smooth frames $E_i$ on each.
On overlaps you fix $E_{i+1}$ so that they meet smoothly.

This is not particularly special to frames. Think of how you'd define a smooth vector field for a curve $I \hookrightarrow M$ for a smooth bundle $E\to M$.

I see. But How should I fix $E_{i+1}$?

You can do it using a partition of unity  $\rho_i$. Then you define $E'{i,j} := \rho_i E{i,j} + \rho_{i+1} E_{i+1,j}$ for the $j$-th vector.

Which might not be a frame, for example the resulting vector might vanish

Right, the partition needs to be on the group action instead. You can use the exponential map for this purpose $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(n)\to SO(n)$
